# How to convert a stringvar into a integer in python?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have been learning gui in python. But I don't know how to convert a stringvar into an int so i can use.
I made this score counting program.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('300x300')
labelFrame = Frame(root)
labelFrame.pack(side='top')
topFrame = Frame(root)
bottomFrame = Frame(root)
topFrame.pack()
bottomFrame.pack(side='bottom')

l1 = Label(labelFrame, text='adi').pack(side='left')
l2 = Label(labelFrame, text='      appa  ').pack(side='left')
l3 = Label(labelFrame, text='      amma').pack(side='left')



class adi:
   def enter(self):
       self.entry = Entry(root, width=5)
       self.entry.pack(side='left')
       self.entry = StringVar(self.entry)
       self.entry = int(self.entry)

   def submit(self):
       self.middleFrame = Frame(root)
       self.middleFrame.pack()
       if self.entry < 250:
           self.eentry = StringVar(self.entry)
           self.label = Label(middleFrame, text=eentry, 
width=6).pack(side='left')
      else:
          self.label1 = Label(middleFrame, text='your out', 
width=6).pack(side='left')


adi = adi()

button = Button(topFrame, text=' enter  ', width=5, 
command=adi.enter()).pack(side='left')
button2 = Button(topFrame, text='enter 2', width=5, 
command=adi.enter()).pack(side='left')
button3 = Button(topFrame, text='enter 3', width=5, 
command=adi.enter()).pack(side='left')
button4 = Button(bottomFrame, text='submit', width=5, 
command=adi.submit()).pack(side='bottom')

root.mainloop()
```

But when I run this,

```
C:\Users\adithya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe C:/Users/adithya/Desktop/python/Adithya.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/adithya/Desktop/python/Adithya.py", line 37, in <module>
    button = Button(topFrame, text=' enter  ', width=5, command=adi.enter()).pack(side='left')
  File "C:/Users/adithya/Desktop/python/Adithya.py", line 23, in enter
    self.entry = int(self.entry)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'StringVar'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This Happens.
Please help me in how to convert a stringvar into an int

Comment: There are numerous other issues with this code, but `self.entry.get()` should retrieve the string value from the `StringVar`.

Comment: Some of the other issues are `command=adi.enter()` should probably be `command=adi.enter` and likewise for the other buttons.